# Trouble accessing array value in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to grab `[value]` in the array dump below.

I can get the value for `[name]` but not sure how to get to the array `[field_model_display_name]` inside the array:

```
       foreach ($taxonomy_names as $taxonomy_name){

            $display = $taxonomy_name->name;
            $api_options[$taxonomy_name->name] = $display;
       }
```

This code gets me `02072017-aprm-222`. How do I set the display name `02072017 APRM 222`?

```
Array
(
[436] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 436
        [vid] => 5
        [name] => 02072017-aprm-222
        [description] => desc
        [format] => 
        [weight] => 0
        [vocabulary_machine_name] => smartdocs_models
        [field_model_display_name] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => 02072017 APRM 222
                                [format] => 
                                [safe_value] => 02072017 APRM 222
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: Look at the docs for [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

Comment: `$display = $taxonomy_name->field_model_display_name['und'][0]['value'];`

Comment: Fantastic! thx!

Comment: Who gave the right answer?

Comment: @NickJ - Abracadaver did. Your way is possible too, but he was asking how to access that array value.